# Multiply Dense Rectangular Matrix by Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm using Python, Numpy and Scipy packages to do matrix computations.  I am attempting to perform the calculation `X.transpose() * W * X` where X is a 2x3 dense matrix and W is a sparse diagonal matrix. (Very simplified example below)

```
import numpy
import scipy.sparse as sp

X = numpy.array([[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2]])

W = sp.spdiags([1, 2], [0], 2, 2).tocsr()
```

I need to find the product of the Dense Matrix X.transpose and sparse matrix W.

The one method that I know of within scipy does not accept a sparse matrix on the right hand side.

```
>>> sp.csr_matrix.dot(X.transpose(), W)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method dot() must be called with csr_matrix instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)
```

Is there a way to multiply a sparse and dense matrix where the sparse matrix is the term on the right within scipy?  If not, what is the best way to do this without turning my W into a dense matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is associative, so you can always first compute `W * X`:

```
>>> X.T.dot(W.dot(X))
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

If you really have to compute `X.T * W`, the first dense, the second sparse, you can let the sparse matrix `__mul__` method take care of it for you:

```
>>> X.T * W
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 4]])
```

Actually, for your use case, if you use `np.matrix` instead of `np.array`, your particular operation becomes surprisingly neat to code:

```
>>> Y = np.matrix(X)
>>> Y.T * W * Y
matrix([[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]])
```